# C++ how to call templated constructor when type deduction impossible

Tags: c++, templates

There are no problems compiling this code:

```
struct A
{
    template<typename T>
    void f(int) {}
};

A a;
a.f<double>(42);
```

However, similar code with templated constructor does not compile:

```
struct A
{
    template<typename T>
    A(int) {}
};

A a<double>(42);
```

Gcc gives the following error in the last line: *error: unexpected initializer before '<' token*

Is there a way to make constructor example work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to explicitly specify templates for a constructor, as you cannot name a constructor.

Depending on what you're trying to do, this can be used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct A
{
    template <typename T>
    struct with_type {};

    template<typename T>
    A(int x, with_type<T>)
    {
        std::cout << "x: " << x << '\n'
                  << "T: " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a(42, A::with_type<double>());
}
```

This "cheats" by taking advantage of type deduction.

This is quite unorthodox, though, so there's probably a better way of doing what you need.